# Can the ~/.john/john.pot file be used forever?

Tags: password

If I use john for getting weak passwords in ex.: 2010, then can I use the john.pot file later or there could be situations when the hash is the same, but the passwords differ?

Comment: what's a *.pot file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can use your old `john.pot` file.

Because password hashes of current systems are usually additionally secured by [salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) and the used hash algorithms are quite strong, is improbable that you find a [hash collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision). But in the unlikely case, that you find one, both password should work on the target system.